# flutter: catch TextFormField state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using text form field. By using validator I am change the border color around it.

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (final p0) {
    if (p0!.isEmpty) return 'No empasspty';
    return null;
  },
),
```

Now when for first time I run *form.currentState.validate* it's border changed to error state means red.
Now at this time I want to **catch the state** of TextFormField! means I want to **catch error state or something like that** to do something else.

Is it possible to get TextFormField state? or Is it possible to get state with `FormField` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but what you can do is, using the same code.

```
TextFormField(
   validator: (final p0) {
    if (p0!.isEmpty){
      // do you work here you want to do on error
      return 'No empasspty';    
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks bro  but I know this solution but I am looking for a clean way, means I want for example `FormField` and get state, but thanks for your answer.